# Less file not found

Tags: css, less

I am most probably doing something really stupid but I just can't figure it out. It just keeps saying file not found. I tried using crunch and the same error. The file is right there and I am positive the location is right. [image]

Comment: Try removing your first `/`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. **1.** Show us your full structure? **2.** What server are you using? **3.** Which is your root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright figured it out. So I learned that in Less, if I open a file inside a folder, I need not reference the @import files from root. I removed the folder reference and kept the file name only and it worked.